# What are some basic methods to solve a recursive function of the shape $f_n = \alpha f_{n-1} + \beta f_{n-2}$ where $\alpha, \beta \in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, determinant, recursive-algorithms, tridiagonal-matrices

I want to understand a little bit more about determining the determinant of tridiagonal matrices. These determinants are (mostly) of the form 
$$f_n = \alpha f_{n-1} + \beta f_{n-2}$$ where $\alpha, \beta \in\mathbb{R}$.

I have a hard time finding literature on how to solve this. Anyone that can help me out?

Comment: This  seems to be a topic of the calculi of finite differences

Comment: Start from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_difference_equation